# How to add multi sign master wallet to a smart contract

Tags: ether, tokens

How can I add a Multi Sign Master wallet features to a Smart Contract

Answer (score 1):

Did you check multi sign wallet from gnosis ?

https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet